# PDF created using FOP and JAVA not displaying in IE 6 but works fine in IE 8

Tags: java, pdf, internet-explorer-6, apache-fop

I have created a report in PDF using Java and FOP, the report displays fine in IE 7, IE 8 , Firefox and Chrome. Only IE 6 gives PDF corrupted error. I have checked all the content type and headers everything looks good. Could someone please provide a pointer on this.

I am setting the belwo response headers

```
response.setContentType ("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=export.pdf");
```

I Googled a lot with no luck

Any help on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: You should use `attachment`, not `inline`; are you serving the file without outputting anything else in the page (as you should)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=export.pdf");
```